# Does Jews for Judaism have disputed ideas or could it be distributed to christians to enrich their knowledge?

Tags: christianity, politics-government, anti-semitism, organizations, judaism

Does Jews for Judaism have disputed ideas or could it be distributed to christians to increase their knowledge?

https://jewsforjudaism.org/

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: Please, please, please! Leave the Christians alone. Why go pick a fight? Don't get me wrong, we need to be prepared to respond to missionaries, But don't think that aha, you're going to be the one who will make all the Christians go "oh gee never mind!"

Comment: Jews for Judaism is a response to Jews for J- the guy with the December birthday. It says right on their own site- it is to keep *Jews* Jewish. Nothing about getting Christians or anyone else to join us.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Chana and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Shalom it's hard to fathom, I still scratch my head about it, but there are, unbelievably, tons of Christians who want to hear from Jews. We also have to be able to teach them something when they come asking. Jews for Judaism is a great source for that

Answer (score 4):

Its a kosher frum organization if that's what you're wondering, Rabbi Skobac (Jews for Judaism Canada) is a great source for Jewish wisdom. I personally know a non-jew who became a ben noach (a righteous non-jew) due to his videos, and the Rabbi's positions are very normative in Orthodox Judaism.

Comment: Yes, BUT it is not our place to go actively preaching anti-Christianity to Christians.

Comment: @Shalom that's technically not true. The only reason we don't is because it is dangerous. Nowadays it is arguably less dangerous, and there are many Christians hoping to hear from us. Being active about it maybe not but one should always be ready to help a Christian who needs help coming back to Hashem. R Skobac is a very good resource to forward to them, which is all the question is coming to ask?

Comment: @RabiKaii a) איבה is not only still an issue, it is one that has only increased in recent years b) our resources and energies are more appropriately directed first towards our own and only after the rest of the world. Certainly if someone approaches us, seeking the truth, we should not turn them away... but we should not be chasing after gentiles with Torah.